# How do I run my PHP code on the click of a button?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a website for school project. I want the schoolResponse() function to happen after clicking the Submit button. If I remove the jQuery function it works but then it shows a default value when I load the page.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>NHG</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/resposive.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
            <div id="main-head">
              <a href="#"><h2 id="main-heading">sKoolBook</h2></a>
            </div>
    </header>
    <section>
      <div id="container">
        <div id="wrapper">
          <form method="POST">
            <select name="school">
              <option value="none" name="none">Please Select a School...</option>
              <option value="NHG">New Horizon Gurukul</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" class="button"/>
            <?php
              error_reporting(0);
              $school = $_POST['school'];
              function schoolResponse() {
                if ($_POST['school'] == 'none'){ 
                  echo 'nothing';
                } else {
                  echo 'something';
                }
              }
            ?>
            <script>
              $('.button').click(
                function(
                  <?php schoolResponse(); ?>
                );
              );
            </script>
          </form> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Server-side and client-side languages don't interact or share variables. PHP runs on the server and generates HTML and JavaScript, which eventually run afterwards in a completely different computer.

Comment: i understood that m just asking a solution to run the schoolResponse() function on the click of the submit button. Just want to know that much.

Comment: For that, you need to resubmit the page to the server so it runs again with the new values (e.g. using a form) or issue an AJAX call to a separate script and inject the value wherever you need it..

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve it like this. Here is one solution:

```
         <?php
          error_reporting(0);
          $school = $_POST['school'];
          function schoolResponse() {
            if ($_POST['school'] == 'none'){ 
              echo 'nothing';
            } else {
              echo 'something';
            }
          }

          if($_POST['school']) schoolResponse();

        ?>
```

It would be better if you replace `error_reporting(0);` with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` for example, because otherwise php errors will be disabled.

And remove this part:

```
        <script>
          $('.button').click(
            function(
              <?php schoolResponse(); ?>
            );
          );
        </script>
```

But it is very very basic example.

Comment: `error_reporting(0);` disables error reporting. You probably meant `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: with error_reporting(E_ALL); it will be better ... just used part of the code in the question ... may be @Shreyas Sreenivasa needs error_reporting(0), I don`t know, but thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery/AJAX to do this.

```
<script>
                  $('.button').click(
                    $.ajax({
                       url: 'yoururl.php',
                       data: $("form").serialize(), //Better to put an ID to  the form or something
                       success: function(data){
                          //DO something with your data
                     }

        })
                  );
                </script>
```

There are other functions you should check to properly use ajax requests.

In yoururl.php you should do something like

```
$school = $_POST['school'];
          function schoolResponse() {
            if ($_POST['school'] == 'none'){ 
              echo 'nothing';
            } else {
              echo 'something';
            }
          }
```

Comment: Better to put an ID to  the form or something, do u mean like putting an id to the form and typing it there? What should i do with my data?

Comment: Update: Which data are you talking about? The one in the yoururl.php?

Comment: Better to put an ID to the form, so in case there are more forms on the view, you make sure you submit the one you need.